# What is the best practice to override pod file methods in objective-c or swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I've recently begun to use third party frameworks that are open source within my own projects because it could cut my development time in half.  While doing this I've noticed that when I manipulate the implementation files that come from doing a pod install then another developer who downloads the project doesn't have access to my unique changes because they will do a pod install on their own computer therefore my changes aren't shown.  What is the best practice to achieve the override?  I'm thinking that I should create a file within the project which overrides methods from doing a pod install such as a category and/or extension?  Is this a feasible process or should I consider another approach?

Comment: If possible, use yourself wrappers where you create your own subclass of third parties code and then override the targets methods and let the other developer see your wrapper. If not, if I understood correctly, you are modifying files that are in the third party pod, that's strange. If that's really the case, your code might be erased once you do a `pod update`. Maybe the third party isn't was you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fork (clone) the project, make the changes and push it to your repo. Other users can than use your code changes. Never make code changes directly in the source files that are located in the pod folder, as you will lose every change when you update that pod.

Alternatively create your own pod, add the pod you want to modify as a dependency and extend it in the development pod, than push it to your repo.

Comment: Thanks, the forking (clone) process makes sense however I DO want to manipulate the source files.  I have experienced the harshness of losing my changes after the pod was downloaded by another developer or updated.  Is the only work around the alternative method you've mentioned by creating my own pod?  Your steps sound a little confusing but I can research

Comment: Yes, you need your own project/pod. You will learn alot about version control and dependency management by forking the project :)

Comment: Note that you might loose all updates from that third library and you might need to check them manually. If they fix issues, etc, being on your own branch/version. Cherry picks might be needed.

Comment: @Larme You can watch the repositories with third party software, but yea you need to check if the project has been updated. If so the data needs to be fetched again...

Comment: @J.Doe Indeed, but that's a manual check, while updating a pod regularly does the job (even if I'd recommend to just let the update to patch/minors for bug fix) and look from time to time to the third party repo.

Comment: @Larme In my private pods, I add a suffix to the current version. So if the version of the upstream is 1.0.1, my private repo version is 1.0.1.1. If the 'real' project will update his project and I run pod udpate in my project, the pod will switch from source (strange, but good). I than know I must fetch the updates from the upstream to my forked project :)